# Replace {something} inside a string with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I have a string like:

```
const string = "Use this {amount} to bring a little joy into someone else's life."

const amount  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // Assume it gave me 34 this time.

const replacedString = // Somehow replace "{amount}" inside string with actual amount variable.
```

I want his for not only "{amount}" this could be anything like "{abc}", "{foo}", "{bar}" etc...

Use case for this is something like:

I have array of random string containing strings which have replaceable variables inside them like:

```
const array = [
    "string 1 have {amount}",
    "string 2 have {amount}  as well as {user}",
    "string 3 have {amount} as well as {user} and their {bank.balance}"
]
```

Now a function returns random elemnt from this array in a variable:

```
const response = getRandomElem(array) // This is a custom function
```

Now I want to use a replace method which I described above so that I can replace the variables.

I know intermediate javascript, so please include examples so that i can understand.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, but i know about template literals but they are not helpful in my specified usecase...

Comment: Instead of creating your own templating engine, you could use an existing one. Like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs), or any of the other templating engines: [npm `keywords: template`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Atemplate&ranking=popularity) or [npm `keywords: "template engine"`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3A%22template%20engine%22&ranking=popularity)

Comment: @AkT-01 Why not? If not, what's wrong with existing template solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this one-liner!

```
const replace = (string, object) => string.replaceAll(/\{([^}]+)\}/gi, (_, a) => a.split('.').reduce((b, c) => b?.[c], object));
```

---

You'll need to define your replacements as key-value pairs like this:

```
const repl = {
  amount: 100,
  user: "Michael Jackson",
  bank: {
    balance: 100
  }
}
```

A simple example here:

```js
const array = [
    "string 1 have {amount}",
    "string 2 have {amount}  as well as {user}",
    "string 3 have {amount} as well as {user} and their {bank.balance}"
]
const repl = {
  amount: 100,
  user: "Michael Jackson",
  bank: {
    balance: 100
  }
}
const replace = (string, object) => string.replaceAll(/\{([^}]+)\}/gi, (_, a) => a.split('.').reduce((b, c) => b?.[c], object));
console.log(array.map(e => replace(e, repl)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a "template context" object that contains all the replacement values. Then, iterate over each template and use the context to generate the resulting strings.
Then, iterate over the template and use the context to generate the resulting string:

```
Hello{name}, welcome to {project}
```

You could create a context object like this:

```
const context = { name: 'John', project: 'MyProject' };


let output = ''

Object.keys(context).forEach(key => { const regexp = new RegExp(`{${key}}`, 'g')
output = template.replace(regexp, context[key]); })
console.log(output); // Hello John, welcome to MyProject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by replace the `{` into a template literal syntax and then interpolate the string into a template string.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input array
const arr = [
  "string 1 have {amount}",
  "string 2 have {amount}  as well as {user}",
  "string 3 have {amount} as well as {user} and their {bank.balance}"
];

// Variables holding the values
const amount  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
const user = 'Alpha';
const bank = {
    balance: 500
};

// Iterating the array to map the values against each '{...}'
const res = arr.map(str => {
  // replacing the '{' with '${' to support the template literal format.
  str = str.replace(/{/g, '$\{')
  // Interpolate the string into a template string.
  return new Function(`return \`${new String(str)}\`;`)();
});
  
// Final output
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use replace() function.

```
var name = 'John'
var age = 25;
var message = 'Hello, {name}! You have {age} years of age.'
message = message.replace('{name}', name).replace('{age}', age);
```

Comment: The problem is that the templates are arbitrary and the replace targets can be paths. You'd need a "context" w/ the replace values and recursive path generation to match the targets. This exists in most (all?) template engines.

Comment: yeah template engine fits my needs.